# I met an Error: line 21, in <module> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
Q = np.loadtxt(open("D:\data_homework_4\Q.csv","rb"), delimiter = ",", skiprows = 0)
b = np.loadtxt(open("D:\data_homework_4\B.csv","rb"), delimiter = ",", skiprows = 0)

def f(x):
    return 1/2 * x.T @ Q @ x + b.T @ x

def gradient(x):
    return Q @ x - b

n = 2000
x_t = np.zeros((100, 1))
alpha = 0.1
beta = 0.3
eta_t = 3.887e-6

for t in range(n + 2):
    g_t = gradient(x_t)
    k = 0
    while True:
        if f(x_t - beta**k * g_t) <= f(x_t) - alpha * beta**k * np.linalg.norm(g_t)**2:
            eta_t = beta**k
            break
        k += 1
    x_t -= eta_t * g_t
print(x_t)
```

line 21 is

```
if f(x_t - beta**k * g_t) <= f(x_t) - alpha * beta**k * np.linalg.norm(g_t)**2:
```

Q is 100x100, b is 100x1, x is 100x1. I looked up similiar errors, but none of them are like mine. Can somebody help me with this error. Thank you.

Comment: `f`is an array. You can't call an array. You had a function called `f` but then you assigned an array to that name.

Comment: There are lots of `ambiguity` posts where an array comparison is in an `if` statement.  What do you expect this line to do?  Show us what the `...<=...` expression is like (type, shape, dtype), and tell us what is supposed to happen.

Comment: You could break that line into parts in temporary variables and experiment with them. Just as a starter, `foo = f(x_t - beta**k * g_t) <= f(x_t) - alpha * beta**k * np.linalg.norm(g_t)**2` And then what would foo be? If its an array, you can't use it with an if. You have to decide what characteristics of the array make it true or false. As mentioned in the error calling `.any()` or `.all()` on the array are two good choices for making that decision.

Comment: This question should be clarified. What do you intend the less-than operator to do when given two arrays?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes that's the problem. thanks

Answer (score 1):

As it says, in the `if` condition you are comparing between 2 arrays - both of which has multiple values and the if condition evaluates all of them but doesn't know how to collapse them into a single value of Truth - that's why it's asking you to use `any` or `all`:

Try this for example :

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([2,3])
arr1 = np.array([1,4])
arr, arr1

if (arr<arr1):
    pass
```

**It would give you the same error that you have.**

> And to solve that I've added an `all` condition so that all the
> elements in those arrays have to satisfy the `<` condition

So:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([2,3])
arr1 = np.array([1,4])
arr, arr1

if (arr<arr1).all():
    pass
```

Think about what makes sense in your case and use that (be it `any` or `all`)